# generated file hosting in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, download

I'd like to prompt the user to download a file, generate it once they accept, and delete the file once they have made the transfer (if they accept the download.)

Does anyone know the c sharp or html code to achieve something like this?

Thanks.

Comment: what type of file it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user accepts the download (ie. click on a button):

1. Generate CSV file and save it to temporary folder (use File class utility methods to get a temporary path)
2. Use

   Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
   Response.AppendHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=file.csv");
3. Call `Response.WriteFile` passing the file path as argument, as generated before, then `Response.Flush()` to make sure all the file was sent
4. `finally`, delete the file

Comment: Actually, when I do this, I get the rest of the page as html injected at the end of the csv file.  Any ideas why that is and how to fix it?  It's like I need it to stop rendering the page and sending it to response...

Comment: Well... I forgot to tell you do Response.End() in the finally block ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a file handler **ashx** for that eg, **download.ashx**
and here is a fast example what you can have inside...

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    // example for the csv
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
    // what is the file name that the user see to save
    context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + cFileNameToShowAndDownload);

    context.Response.Write("here is your text to send");

    context.Response.Flush();
}
```

Comment: Note that you may return file response to a regular GET or POST request to ASPX page if you make sure there is no controls rendered yet (Request.Clear and CompleteRequest - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f417efst.aspx )